# NoSuchMethodError from dependencies when using spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, dependencies, apache-commons-cli

I'm trying to submit a JAR to my `Apache Spark 2.2.1` cluster using `Scala 2.11`. I included some extra dependencies in my JAR, namely *Apache Commons CLI*, and packaged it all into a fat JAR. However, I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodError` when I submit my Spark application. I'm quite sure that it's not due to inconsistency in Scala versions, but rather something weird with dependencies.

The command is simply `spark-submit myjar.jar [arguments]`

This is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.commons.cli.Options.addRequiredOption(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/
>   String;)Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Options;
>         at xyz.plenglin.aurum.spark.RunOnSpark$.main(RunOnSpark.scala:46)
>         at xyz.plenglin.aurum.spark.RunOnSpark.main(RunOnSpark.scala)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Running `java -jar myjar.jar [arguments]` works without any issues. Peeking inside the JAR, I see `org.apache.commons.cli.Options` where it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I fixed it by adding the `--driver-class-path` argument to my `spark-submit` command.

So the command looks like:

```
$ spark-submit --driver-class-path myjar.jar myjar.jar [arguments]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, worked well, thanks. I was using --jars but it did not help.